# Swift constraints programmatically creates odd behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm attempting to layout all my constraints programmatically because I have to add and remove boxes based on user input.  When I run a function which applies all my constraints in ViewDidLoad, it works great.  But if I run it again, after removing them all, 2 of my labels disappear behind my navigation bar.  I can't figure out why!  Keep in mind if I never run the function pasted below, my screen is blank because I have no constraints on start up from the storyboard.  My goal is to figure out why my label and button disappear when the same piece of code is run a second time.

Below is a picture when the code, which I'll post below, is run initially in ViewDidLoad:

[image: Constraints run during ViewDidLoad]

Below is a picture when the same piece of code is run again afterwards when the next button is pressed.  This is just a test, in the future I'll need to reset all my constraints after changing them:

[image: Constraints run again later (when next button is pressed)]

And Below is a picture of the debug view hierarchy afterwards:
[image]

The code that creates the constraints is below.  Keep in mind I have only 5 elements, my main view, scroll view, aglAltitudeLabel which is the label, nextButton which is the button, and aglAltitude which is the text input:

```
    //Remove all pre-existing contraints
    var constraints:NSArray = aglAltitudeLabel.constraints()
    aglAltitudeLabel.removeConstraints(constraints)
    constraints = aglAltitude.constraints()
    aglAltitude.removeConstraints(constraints)
    constraints = nextButton.constraints()
    nextButton.removeConstraints(constraints)
    constraints = scrollView.constraints()
    scrollView.removeConstraints(constraints)
    constraints = view.constraints()
    self.view.removeConstraints(constraints)
    constraints = calculateButton.constraints()
    calculateButton.removeConstraints(constraints)

    //Make scrollview fit normal View, accounting for Navigation bar
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[first(\(self.view.frame.width))]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["first": scrollView]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-64-[first(\(self.view.frame.height-64))]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["first": scrollView]))

    //Set the heights for the label and button
    let labelHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aglAltitudeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
    scrollView.addConstraint(labelHeight)
    let buttonHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)
    scrollView.addConstraint(buttonHeight)

    //Setup the vertical layout
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[first(30)]-8-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["first": aglAltitude]))


    //Setup the horizontal layout
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-8-[first(97)]-8-[second(>=100)]-8-[third(46)]-8-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["first": aglAltitudeLabel, "second": aglAltitude, "third": nextButton]))

    //Align baselines - this also occurs with the option above of AlignAllBaselines and leaving this code out
    let aglLabelBaseline = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aglAltitudeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: aglAltitude, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    scrollView.addConstraint(aglLabelBaseline)
    let nextButtonBaseline = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: aglAltitude, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    scrollView.addConstraint(nextButtonBaseline)

    self.view.layoutSubviews()
```

Thank you for any help.  I'm sure I'm doing 55 things incorrectly.

Edit:  If I change the last section of code from this:

```
    //Align baselines - this also occurs with the option above of AlignAllBaselines and leaving this code out
    let aglLabelBaseline = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aglAltitudeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: aglAltitude, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    scrollView.addConstraint(aglLabelBaseline)
    let nextButtonBaseline = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: aglAltitude, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    scrollView.addConstraint(nextButtonBaseline)
```

To this:

```
    //Align baselines - this also occurs with the option above of AlignAllBaselines and leaving this code out
    let aglLabelBaseline = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aglAltitudeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 14)
    self.view.addConstraint(aglLabelBaseline)
    let nextButtonBaseline = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
    self.view.addConstraint(nextButtonBaseline)
```

it works exactly as I'd expect.  Why the difference?

Comment: It might help to say what you're trying to accomplish (specifically, what elements do you need to remove and re-add) to see if there is a better way. There's no need to add all the constraints in code so you can add/remove views. You could certainly setup the original constraints in the storyboard, and make IBOutlets to them, if you need to modify or remove them (and save them in an array so you can add them back if need be). Another possible solution for this might be to use a table view, where adding and removing rows is easy.

Comment: I agree, that may work.  I like the tableView idea.  But for the sake of understanding Swift and IOS, if I were to try to delete all constraints and re-add them for no reason, why does this not work?

Also, some extra info:  If I take out layoutSubviews() or change it to layoutIfNeeded() I get more strange behavior (everything goes super high up)

Comment: Removing the constraints from you button and label seems to be the problem. There are some constraints (about their content size) that aren't being added back. If you give the button a background color, you will actually see that the background and the title end up in different places when you run the code again. Do the sizes of the button and label ever change, or is it only the position that you need to delete, and then re-add?

Comment: Thanks! Messing with that, I've found a few things.  The align baselines seems to be broken.  If I change the //Align Baselines code to align top to scroll view by 8, it works (though not nicely aligned).  Why does the align baselines not work properly?

Comment: I edited my post to incorporate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your requirements are, it's hard to give you good advice. Here is an example of how I might do it. I added all the views in code, and added background colors to the views so I could better see their layout. I'm assuming that the scroll view is only added once, and never removed, so it's constraints to self.view should only be added once in viewDidLoad. Same goes for the height of the the other views if you don't need to change them (notice that I add the height constraints to the view itself, not its superview). The only thing that needs to be removed and re-added are the constraints between the scroll view and its subviews.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var aglAltitudeLabel = UILabel()
    var aglAltitude = UITextField()
    var nextButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
    var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var viewsDict: NSDictionary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aglAltitudeLabel.text = "AGL Altitude"
        aglAltitudeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        aglAltitudeLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        aglAltitude.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        aglAltitude.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        aglAltitudeLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: aglAltitudeLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
        scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        nextButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        nextButton.setTitle("Next", forState: .Normal)
        nextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        nextButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(aglAltitude)
        scrollView.addSubview(aglAltitudeLabel)
        scrollView.addSubview(nextButton)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)

        viewsDict = ["scrollView": scrollView, "aglAltitudeLabel": aglAltitudeLabel, "aglAltitude":aglAltitude, "nextButton":nextButton] as NSDictionary

        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[scrollView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-64-[scrollView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        self.redoConstraints()
    }


    @IBAction func redoConstraints() {

        scrollView.removeConstraints(scrollView.constraints())

        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[aglAltitude(30)]-8-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-8-[aglAltitudeLabel(97)]-8-[aglAltitude(>=100)]-8-[nextButton(46)]-8-|", options: .AlignAllBottom , metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    }
}
```

Notice that I took the fixed width and height out of the constraints for the scroll view. There's no need for that, and it would cause it to not work correctly on rotation.

Comment: Thank you!  There were a few things you did here I was doing wrong.  The first, and the biggest, is you did not remove autoresizingmaskintoconstraints for self.view!  That fixed it all.  I also realized the way I was removing constraints did not work since that is only for subviews of the labels and buttons, I have to remove the subview and re-add it.  Lastly, I took your advice for splitting it up and not specifying width and height.  If you have more information, could you specify why it's such a big deal for the autoresizingmask to be on for self.view?

Comment: @Diesel, I'm not sure why you shouldn't do that for a controller's self.view, I just know that you shouldn't. You should only set that to false if you're adding constraints between that view and its superview, something that you never do for self.view (I'm not even sure that the system adds constraints between the window and self.view).